# Python-midi has no attribute Pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, midi, python-packaging

I want to use the `python-midi` package (from `https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi`).
Hwever there is an error when I use it.

```
import midi
pattern = midi.Pattern()
```

When I run it, I have the following error:

```
pattern = midi.Pattern()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Pattern'
```

I tried to install this package with:

- `pip install git+https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi@feature/python3`
- `pip install python-midi`
- `python setup.py install` (in downloading the projet)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `midi.py` by any chance?

Comment: No unfortunately. I have no file named midi.py where I run this code. But I will check in other files if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I use this command "**pip freeze**" to know wihch packages I downloaded. Then I uninstall all packages concerning midi. And finally I downloaded the package with this command "**sudo -H pip install python-midi**". And I have no issues when I run my code anymore. 
We can also do if we use python3:

- sudo -H pip3 install git+https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi@feature/python3